# Neo4j - querying the nodes based on time property with "<" or ">" using Scala/Neo4j API

Tags: java, scala, lucene, neo4j, cypher

Am able to query the nodes based on a keyword like below

```
val articles = article_content_index.query("article_data: keyword")
```

But, I also need to query the nodes based on the time property, I tried doing this

```
val time = 1000
val articles = article_content_index.query("article_data: keyword AND time >"+time).iterator()
```

I got the **java.lang.NullPointerException.** So, How do I query the nodes based on time property?

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace, and the versions of Neo4j/Scala/classpath you are using?

Comment: Maybe it's an option to use a range query, e.g. time:[a_date TO another_date]. Bear in mind that you should store dates as longs.